# Does the notation "$a,b\neq 0$" mean that $a$ and $b$ must both be non-zero?

Tags: notation

Consider the statement:

> $$a^2+b^2+2ab=0, \text{where}\; a,b\neq 0$$

What does "$a,b\neq0$" mean? Is it necessary that both $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq0$ simultaneously? Can one of them be $0$ and the other be non-zero?

Comment: Yes, simultaneously $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$, i.e. none of $a,b$ is $0$

Comment: It means both of the them are non-zero.  Usually.  I wouldn't say it is "necessary" but that that is the standard meaning.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The comma notation stands for *and*. But you should be able to tell why this condition makes sense in this context.

Comment: In this particular case, the question is pointless because $(a+b)^2=0$ implies $a=-b$.

Answer (score 4):

Every time I saw the notation $a,b\neq 0$, I understood it as "both are nonzero". That said, this is still notation, so double check if that condition makes sense.

Comment: So that set of points where either a or b is zero, isn't considered. Is that correct?

Comment: @GKLB That's how it's usually understood, yeah.